# Using a comma before a tag question.

Tags: punctuation, commas

Can anyone please help me out and indicate the mistake in this exchange?

“Is John ill? He’s lost a lot of weight.”
“Yes, he is rather slender these days, isn’t  he?”

I am not so sure about the way the second sentence is punctuated.

Answer (score 1):

*Punctuation* is a matter of style and preference and it largely depends on which style book you or your editor use. However, using a comma is not as much confusing as other punctuation marks.

According to the linked [Commas: Quick Rules](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/) by Purdue University:

> Use commas after introductory a) clauses, b) phrases, or c) **words that come before the main clause**... Common introductory words that should be followed by a comma include **yes**, however, well.

1. The word *yes* is an [interjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) and it is usually placed at the beginning of a sentence. It could be considered as a *word that come before the main clause* which requires a comma.

> Use a comma near the end of a sentence to separate **contrasted
>   coordinate elements** or to indicate a distinct pause or shift.

2. *isn't he* in the sentence is called a [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) which could be considered as one of *contrasted coordinate elements*. Therefore, a comma is required before the tag question.

Comment: Thank you for the help Rathony. So, if the second sentence is correct does that mean the first sentence has some errors?   This exchange is part of an exercise and I have to identify the mistake, which I am not able to point out.

Comment: @MairaRaheel There is no mistake. What makes you think the first sentence should have some errors just because the second sentence doesn't? I would only rephrase the first sentence to "He seems to have lost a lot of weight."

Answer (score 0):

The punctuation in your second sentence is fine

> **Yes, he is rather slender these days, isn’t he?**

These may help you better understand [**here**](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp) and [**here**](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_06.htm)